# How to add parameters with specified prompt

Tags: shell

I want to write a bash shell script, it can accept parameters, and the parameter has prompt, example,

```
./test.sh --version=1.0
```

value `1.0` is the real parameter for my shell, and `--version=` is the prompt

is there any easy way to do it like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have have a look at man(1) getopt.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you mean by "easy" - using getopts should work. A bit of typing, but... Here are some examples to get you started:

- http://rsalveti.wordpress.com/2007/04/03/bash-parsing-arguments-with-getopts/
- [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)
- http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/30/parsing-arguments-in-bash-with-getopts/